# Is there a way to add an item to a list by clicking a link in another list's view?

Tags: list, list-view, lookup-column, list-form

I am currently making a sharepoint Lists application for my company's recruiters to assist in their campus recruiting process. So far this consists of two lists, the first, *Candidates*, is a simple list with a candidate's name, school and other basic information as shown below:
[image]

The other list, *Candidate Feedback*, is a place for our recruiters to give feedback on the candidates and has a one-to-many relationship with the *Candidates* list:
[image]

Ideally what I want is to be able to have a column in the far-right of *Candidates* labeled "Add Feedback for Candidate" with edit buttons similar to the leftmost column. Clicking these buttons should bring up the form for the *Candidate Feedback* list.

I have spent some time digging around but can't find a way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use a script editor or content editor web part on the page sitting above the list view that has a button that redirects the user to the new item form of the child list or opens the child list new item form in a modal.

Comment: Is there a way to do this such that when the form is pulled up it already has the name of the candidate entered in the form?

Comment: That will require some script to to, you would need to pass a param over to the newitem form of the child list and then have code receiving that param that prefills data. That is a more complex method, but it is doable.